# MySQL Syntax errors

Tags: mysql, database, syntax

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
custID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
custName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
custAddress VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_Customer PRIMARY KEY (custID)
),
```

I have this as part of a database I'm setting up, yet whenever I try to run the .sql file that this is included in, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    custID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    custName VARCHAR(' at line 8
```

Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Apart from the last `,` this works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the , from the end `CREATE TABLE` statement

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
  custID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  custName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  custAddress VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_Customer PRIMARY KEY (custID)
)
```

Or use semicolon instead comma:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
      custID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      custName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      custAddress VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT pk_Customer PRIMARY KEY (custID)
    );
```

Comment: The same as in my original post

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but I solved this now. Turns out each time I create a table (I have 5) on the closing ')' I needed a ';'. Adding these to the end of each CREATE TABLE has fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You have comma at the end if you remove that it is working fin for me.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
custID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
custName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
custAddress VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_Customer PRIMARY KEY (custID)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't use "," at the end to separate two sql queries, you have to use ";" and if you are running a single query then you don't need.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
        custID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        custName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        custAddress VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT pk_Customer PRIMARY KEY (custID)
                    )
```